# Disable writing to macOS DNS cache

Tags: networking, macos, dns, privacy, cache

Can writing to the macOS DNS cache be disabled through configuration, so that DNS resolution doesn't leave a mark on the filesystem?

The context is that I want to avoid logging the details of network requests on my local machine as much as I can, reliant on a VPN for simple local-remote encryption, *without* resorting to browsing via Tor, a virtual machine (e.g. Qubes) or live OS (e.g. Tails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS doesn't cache DNS to the filesystem - it's in memory only and clears on shutdown. It doesn't log DNS queries by default either.

The only way to truly disable DNS caching is by stopping the entire DNS service `mDNSResponder`, which will break resolving names. The OS needs *somewhere* to hold them for apps to grab once resolved. You could clear the cache regularly to simulate a short-lived cache though.

Note that some software like Safari may keep its own DNS cache, separate from the OS anyways.

Comment: Big if true! Happy to accept this as the answer if you have any references for the assertion that macOS doesn't cache DNS to the filesystem.

Comment: @yellow-saint it's standard. It's in the memory of the `mDNSResponder` service process, so restarting the service clears the cache entirely. You *can* dump the cache from the process to a log file like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54151812, but it's not sent to a file by default in any OS. current versions of macos also mark it as "private_data" and require sudo privileges just to view the existing cache (though that process keeps changing in different builds of osx)

Comment: OK cool, thank you :) If anyone can find documentation for this, that would be ideal.